# Relationship with two table

Tags: mysql, database

I'm new to PHP, and I am working on a project for a friend of mine. He needs a system where members can register and upload images.

I have done all of that so far but my main problem is members can only upload a single image to the database seen where the image row is in the table as the registration information.

For example, if you click a single user you'll be able to see all the images which he/she uploaded to the site.

How do I create a table for a user's images and have it interact with the user's information table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a new table into the system, which will hold multiple rows for same `member_id` (*1 to many* relationship).

For example:

```
CREATE TABLE `member_images` (
  `image_id` BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `member_id` BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `image_path` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY(`image_id`),
  KEY (`member_id`)
);
```

Here `PK` (primary key) is on a column different from `member_id`, so this table can hold multiple entries for the same member.